# Binding data in List View

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using `JQUERY` to call `WebMethod` function from aspx.cs page and try to bind those values in `DIV` but after return values from function Jquery shows `error` message..What is the mistake on this Jquery...

`Jquery`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).on('click', 'input', function () {

          var key = $(this).find('lb' + this.id).text();
          var val = 'lb' + this.id;
          var lbltext = document.getElementById(val).innerHTML;
          var names = [];
          $('input:checked').each(function () {
              names.push(this.id);
          });

          $.ajax(
                {

                    alert: alert(),
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "CandidateManagement.aspx/BindDatatablelist",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: '{value: "' + names + '" }',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (json) {
                        var output = $('#MyTemplate').parseTemplate(json);
                        $('#MyTemplateOutput').html(output);

                        //Add hover capabilities
                        $('tbody > tr').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function () {
                            $(this).toggleClass('hover');
                        });
                    },
                                error: function (json) {
                                alert("Error");
                             }

                });

      });
 </script>
```

`C# code`

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static List<Admin_CandidateManagement> BindDatatablelist(string value)
    {

        Admin_CandidateManagement admincandi = new Admin_CandidateManagement();
        string strSrcQry = admincandi.getSrcQryExpr(value);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        Recruitment recOBJ = new Recruitment();
        admincandi.recOBJ.GetAllCandiDeatForAdvaceSearch(ref admincandi.dsCandiDeat, strSrcQry);
        dt = admincandi.dsCandiDeat.Tables[0];

        List<Admin_CandidateManagement> details = new List<Admin_CandidateManagement>();
        foreach (DataRow dtrow in dt.Rows)
        {
            Admin_CandidateManagement user = new Admin_CandidateManagement();
         // user.CandidateID = dtrow["CandidateId"].ToString();
            user.CandidateName = dtrow["CandiName"].ToString();
            user.CurPosition = dtrow["CurrPosi"].ToString();
            user.TotWorkExp = dtrow["TotWrkExp"].ToString();
            user.Skillset = dtrow["SkillSet"].ToString();
            user.USStatus = dtrow["USStatus"].ToString();
            user.Location = dtrow["Location"].ToString() + "   " + dtrow["JobZipCode"].ToString();
            user.ActiveResume = dtrow["ActiveResume"].ToString();
            details.Add(user);
        }
        return details;
    }
```

Comment: and your `console.log` says?

Comment: `Success:Funtion()` not works here..and it shows error.

Comment: firstly, remove `alert:alert()` from your ajax call

Comment: Even its showa error @AmitSoni

Comment: Use [firbug](http://getfirebug.com/enable) to check for errors

Comment: have you checked the value of the variable json? is it what is expected? is the url working properly?

Comment: S url works properly ..